# Date to SQL in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Using LINQ to Entities.  This code in an anonymous type

```
MessageDate = DateTime.Parse(email.MessageDate),
```

Is throwing this error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

MessageDate is a SQL DateTime and email.MessageDate is a string.

I tried this but it didn't help:

```
MessageDate = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Parse(email.MessageDate)))
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

---

More info:

The string value of email.MessageDate is "Wed, 15 Jun 2011 13:29:00 -0400"

Also, if I just do

```
MesssageDate = Date.Now
```

I get the same error.

Also, it's SQL Server 2005

---

More testing:  I set a breakpoint to see what resolved to true

```
var x = 1;
if (DateTime.Now > System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
    x = 1; // True
if (DateTime.Now < System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
    x = 1;
if (DateTime.Now > System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value)
    x = 1;
if (DateTime.Now < System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value)
    x = 1; // True
if (DateTime.Now < DateTime.MinValue)
    x = 1;
if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.MinValue)
    x = 1; // True
if (DateTime.Now < DateTime.MaxValue)
    x = 1; // True
if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.MaxValue)
    x = 1;
```

So it looks to me that DateTime.Now is within all the valid ranges.

Thank you,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was ridiculously hard to find.  Here is the answer:

LINQ to Entities has some problem with not providing the Date information to a table that has DateTime fields.  So even if you don't need to put data in a DateTime field the Submit won't work unless you do.  So all I did, on the fields where I did not have data to provide, was, for example, this...

```
MessageDeliveryTime = null,
```

Now, the other thing that got me was this. I have a column in the database name Created that auto-populates with getdate().  LINQ to Entities doesn't care about your little default values.  You must pass in something; so just do this:

```
Created = DateTime.Now
```

I hope that the hours of my life that are gone don't go in vain and this will help someone out.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

It is parsing the string fine but unfortunately the valid .net date ranges are not the same as the valid SQL date ranges. email.MessageDate is probably set to DateTime.MinValue which is earlier than the earliest valid SQL date.

Comment: Here is the value of email.MessageDate  "Wed, 15 Jun 2011 13:29:00 -0400"

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(email.MessageDate)` is returning a date outside of the valid SQL date range.  Use a debugger to find out what it is returning. You probably want to pass in a CultureInfo to DateTime.Parse() to force it to interpret the date in the way that you want rather than using the culture info of whatever machine the code is running on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2008 you can use datetime2 instead of datetime type. If you can't change your SQL datatype then I recommend rolling your own "smart" DateTime parser.